# Why does the Eisenstein series $E_2(z)$ diverge?

Tags: complex-analysis, divergent-series, integer-lattices

We know that, given a lattice $\Lambda$ of the complex plane, the Eisenstein series $E_{2k} := \displaystyle\sum_{\substack{\omega \in \Lambda \\ \omega \neq (0,0)}} \frac{1}{|\omega|^{2k}}$ converges for $2k \geq 4$, i.e. for $k \geq 2$. However, I am wondering how $E_1(z)$ does not converge, which is the content of Stein and Shakarchi's complex analysis textbook question 3 from chapter 9, that $$\displaystyle\sum_{1 \leq n^2 + m^2 \leq R^2} \frac{1}{|n\tau + m|^2} = 2\pi \log R + O(1)$$.

I get the picture that we are trying to count all the lattices $\omega \in \Lambda$ inside a circle at the origin of radius $R$, and I also suspect that we are trying to use the fact that $\displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^R \frac{1}{i}$ behaves like $\log R$ for $R$ large enough. However, I am having trouble coming up with a precise argument. On [this document](https://www.studocu.com/row/document/zhejiang-university/%E5%A4%8D%E5%8F%98%E5%87%BD%E6%95%B0/stein%E7%AD%94%E6%A1%881-%E7%AD%94%E6%A1%881/13085445) page 23, it says that the number of $\omega \in \Lambda$ such that $nr \leq |\omega| \leq nR$ is $4n$; why is that true?